# Connect server hosted webapp to local websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, client-side

Has anyone an idea for the following scenario?

I have a RIA-Webapplication (realized in ExtJs). What I want to implement is the possibility to use local ressources like card readers or fingerprint readers or other serial devices and filesystem access.

I thought about implementing this with a local websocket service which has to be installed by our customer before using our RIA the first time. When the webapp is loading it should scan the local machine if a websocket service is available and connect to it.

After that, local events (like new card is beeing read or recognized new finger) should be passed to the browser via websocket connection.

Any ideas how to get started with such a solution?

Comment: Interesting concept, although it sounds a bit like you don't want a in-browser-application but a standalone one.

Answer (score 0):

I have made something like that. Besides the obvious things such as read/write/poll data from the card-readers and so on, you would have to either implement everything yourself or, use a library for technology you are going to employ for your web-server. So, if you use a LAMP solution, i think there are some web-socket libraries for PHP that you can use. However, if you do everything by yourself then you have to implement everything from hand-shaking, to creating data packets. I have done everything from scratch by using .NET and it provides a number of useful libraries such as hashing. Java also would be a good option and have those kind of libraries as well. In general if you doing everything by yourself i would say the trickiest thing would be to split the data you want to transmit among various data packet. It is not that hard to do things from scratch. The RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) helped me a lot. Hopefully, this helps.